# Test react forceUpdate custom hook useEffect/useState

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, react-hooks

I created a custom hook to force a component to update but I'm having issues figuring out how to write a unit test with jest.

This is the hook

```
function useForceUpdate(condition) {
  const [, setState] = useState(0);
  const forceUpdate = () => setState(1);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (condition) {
      forceUpdate();
    }
  }, [condition]);
}

export default useForceUpdate;
```

Comment: It's difficult to say without more context. When you say "test," do you mean a unit test with a library like jest? Or do you just want to check if it works? What problem are you trying to solve with a forced update?

Comment: Sorry about that I meant unit test with jest.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to successfully test this hook this way

```
import React from "react";
import useForceUpdate from "hooks/use-force-update";

const Component = ({ shouldUpdate }) => {
  const hasUpdated = useForceUpdate(shouldUpdate);
  return <div>{hasUpdated}</div>;
};

describe("useForceUpdate", () => {
  let subject;
  let props;

  beforeEach(() => {
    props = { shouldUpdate: true };
    subject = memoize(() => mount(<Component {...props} />));
  });

  describe("when the condition is true", () => {
    it("it calls forceUpdate", () => {
      expect(
        subject()
          .find("div")
          .text()
      ).toBe("1");
    });
  });

  describe("when the condition is false", () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      props = { shouldUpdate: false };
    });
    it("it does not call forceUpdate", () => {
      expect(
        subject()
          .find("div")
          .text()
      ).toBe("0");
    });
  });
});
```